# I have a script that opens a webpage, How can I make the body editable using a Gui through tkinter, essentially creating a new webpage

Tags: python, html, user-interface, tkinter

This is the most I have gotten so far. just need to be able to pull up the GUI to edit body. Need to create a GUI that I can pull up a text box to edit what is in the body. Also not sure if I can add tags in a program. Since I can't plug code in between the Html format how would I go about calling or just pulling the `<h1>` tag to edit?

```
import webbrowser
import os
from tkinter import *

f = open("webgen.html", "w")

html_template = """
<html>

<body>

<h1>

Stay tuned for our amazing summer sale!

</h1>

</body>

</html>
"""
#writing code into file
f.write(html_template)
f.close()

filename = 'file:///'+os.getcwd()+'/' + 'webgen.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename)

window=Tk() #this is the GUI
btn=Button(window, text="To confirm body click here", fg='blue')
btn.place(x=80, y=100)
txtfld=Entry(window, text="", bd=5)
txtfld.place(x=80, y=150)
window.title('Web Generator')
window.geometry("300x200+10+10")
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, the code for writing the contents to the HTML file should be in it's own function, it shouldn't be loose in the .py code. First, the function should use ".get" to grab the text currently in the Entry widget named "txtfld" and save it to a variable:

```
text = txtfld.get()
```

Then, it should use ".format" to create a variable with the HTML code and insert the "text" variable into it:

```
html_template = """
<html>
<body>
<h1>
{}
</h1>
</body>
</html>
""".format(text)
```

Then, it should open the HTML file in write mode, write the "html_template" to the file, then close it. The last thing the function should do is open the HTML file in the webbrowser:

```
f = open("webgen.html", "w")
#writing code into file
f.write(html_template)
f.close()

filename = 'file:///'+os.getcwd()+'/' + 'webgen.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename)
```

Let's say you named the function "Submit". The whole function should look like this:

```
def Submit():
    text = txtfld.get()
    html_template = """
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>
    {}
    </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
    """.format(text)
    f = open("webgen.html", "w")
    #writing code into file
    f.write(html_template)
    f.close()
filename = 'file:///'+os.getcwd()+'/' + 'webgen.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename)
```

Finally, you need to adjust the Button widget to call the "Submit" function:

```
btn=Button(window, text="To confirm body click here", fg='blue', command=Submit)
```